# OrientDB: How to use traverse to get edges?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to use traverse to explore multiple orders of edges away from a specific starting node. For example, using the Grateful Dead graph, I call this command:

`traverse bothE('followed_by') from #15:8 while $depth<3`

I expect this to get two orders of edges. However, all the edges are ones that include the starting node. If instead I use `both('followed_by')` it appears to visit all the desired vertices, but it doesn't report the edges. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `in` edge on `#15:8` record is called `followed_by`, and the out are `sung_by`, `written_by`, `followed_by`, so you can't use `followed_by` name and get also out edges, even if you use `both` in your query:

This one should do it:

`traverse bothE() from #15:8 while $depth<3`

Comment: Try your command - it only gets edges that include #15:8. I'm trying to get the edges that connect *neighbors" of #15:8 to other nodes.

Comment: It will be a big amout of data, can you try something like this one: ```select expand($d)
let $a = (traverse both() from #15:8 while $depth<3),
 $b = (traverse inE("written_by"), inE("sung_by"), inE("followed_by") from $a),
 $c = (traverse outE("written_by"), outE("sung_by"), outE("followed_by") from $a),
 $d = unionAll($b, $c)```